# http versus https for YouTube feed APIs

Tags: youtube-api

The YouTube documentation for the video feeds API is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos

It states:

> To request a feed of all videos uploaded by another user, send a GET request to the following URL. This request does not require authentication.
>
> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/uploads

I have found that the non-SSL format (http) of this API works as well.

I would prefer to use this version of the URL because I do not require SSL. However I am concerned that it is not documented (and thus might be dropped in the future).  So, my question is, is the http form of this API officially supported?

Comment: I can't find much other than the OAuth methods require SSL, hope someone has more to offer: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2

Answer (score 1):

I use HTTP too. The demo page from YouTube does not use HTTPS too: [YouTube Data API](http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html)

You should be perfectly fine by using HTTP.

Comment: Hi Jonny, thanks for the info and the link to the API demo page.

Comment: Indeed; although we recommend HTTPS and certain calls (like those that exchange user credentials for authorization tokens) need to be done via HTTPS, general API calls will also work over HTTP in v1/v2. The upcoming v3 of the YouTube Data API will require HTTPS for all calls, though.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the official recommendation and heads up regarding v3 of the API.